# Why browsers fetch images again after reloading my page?

Tags: cache, xampp

I am developing a web app, and I want all the images (a couple hundred MB worth - 20 000 - 50 000 thumbnails) to be downloaded once and never downloaded again, as those don't really change. Also, those images are downloaded from youtube servers, and I don't want to hammer their servers unnecessarily.

But the problem is that, when I reload the page, the requests start raining again, instead of loading the cached images. This happens when I navigate to my page and when I reload it, but when I open another page and press back the images are loaded from the cache. When I dynamically add new content with JavaScript the images are loaded from the cache as well.

So, what am I missing? I am using XAMPP server on windows 10 to test.

P.S. I am reloading with the reload button near the address bar, not with Ctrl+R or other key combination that cleans the cache.

P.P.S. To clarify before someone comments on that, I am not downloading all those thousands of images at once

Comment: What do the HTTP caching headers contain for these images?

Comment: age     10898
cache-control  public, max-age=86400, no-transform
date    Tue, 28 Sep 2021 12:40:50 GMT
expires    Mon, 27 Sep 2021 16:28:41 GMT

Comment: so, the images are already expired

Comment: Yes, so you need to increase the `max-age` for these images by adjusting Apache2 configuration.

Comment: So, I need to fetch those images through my server first. Thanks a lot, I haven't realized youtube does that. Post as answer so I can accept it please, or I will in few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the HTTP Response caching headers specify a `Max-Age` of 86400 seconds (one day), the browsers will fetch the images when they expire.

You need to increase the `Max-Age` to get them cached indefinitely.